# namespace of DNN's Language class

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, tagprefix

I am trying to configure internationalization for my DNN project. I have added two languages, and now I want to access DNN's *Language* control in order to make it visible on project's pages.
I have found a snippet
`<dnn:LANGUAGE runat="server" ID="dnnLANGUAGE" ShowLinks="True" ...`
and I tried to use it. Compiler does not recognize `dnn:` tagPrefix so I have to register it, that is, I have to pass class's namespace inside *Register* tag in my ascx page. But I can not find the namespace anywhere. I have also browsed www.dnnsoftware.com/dnn-api , but could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following line at the top of your ascx page.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LANGUAGE" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Language.ascx" %>
```